# Is there any stable nosql database for iOS except for Couchbase?

Tags: ios, iphone, nosql, couchdb, couchbase

Is there any stable nosql database for iOS except for Couchbase?
Couchbase is now a beta version which i don't want to use on a app with many users.(Although i like Couchbase very much)

Any suggestions? Special Thx!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several projects to get a CouchDB-compatible API available on mobile devices.

- [TouchDB](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS), a native iOS build
- [PouchDB](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb), an HTML5 implementation, for web and PhoneGap apps

Comment: Now, we should use https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios instead of TouchDB (from TouchDB's developers)

Comment: `TouchDB is the legacy 1.0 version of the project now named Couchbase Lite. Due to the renaming and architectural changes, Couchbase Lite lives in a separate repository (although it inherits from TouchDB.) We don't recommend using TouchDB for any new development:`

Answer (score 6):

**Edit** (April, 2016):

- **[Realm.io](https://realm.io/)** is the way to go nowadays.

---

Also take a look to this Key/value databases that have been ported (wrapped) to iOS:

- LevelDB (Port: [NULevelDB](https://github.com/nulayer/NULevelDB)): Made by Google, and it seems to be one of the fastest out there.
- TokyoCabinet ( Port: [TSDocDB](https://github.com/isaact/TSDocDB)): Very fast, but it seems to be a bit outdated, the official page states that there's a new version (called KyotoCabinet) that is even faster, but for that there's no port (as far as I know). And, is licensed as LGPL (that it seems not to be fully compatible with the AppStore).

Answer (score 3):

I am also looking NoSQL for iOS and found NanoStore

https://github.com/tciuro/NanoStore

Although if you have time to explore, it would be a great experience learning SQLite properly with custom functions. It is very easy to create your own NoSQL database. Just one table for all objects storing dictionaries/json along views/indexes with custom functions.

Making your own solution is not the hard part. The hard work is mapping your objects to the database. This task can grow the complexity of your codebase in most hideous ways and you need to be a very good coder to avoid that. Although maybe you must suffer through such experience if you want to be very good.

One of the most nasty problems will also be the relationships between objects. Solving that is the main goal of CoreData, that is the reason for which you will read around that CoreData is not a database.

Learning SQLite properly, specially where you create custom plugins for it, can open many doors. However be aware that most developers do not care at all about learning those details and will get lost with your code base.

Comment: SQLite works, but seems to be really slow - reading 8000 records into objects from ASCII files took 25s on an iPod Touch 5g and took 3m from a NoSQL db.  I'm going to look into faster read-only key/value stores.